# Evaluate the integral $\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} x \cdot \cot(x) \cdot \csc(x) \mathop{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$  \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}  x \cdot \cot(x) \cdot \csc(x) \mathop{dx}
$$

### Some working

Evaluate the indefinite integral first

Let $u = \csc(x)$ , then $\frac{du}{- \csc(x) \cdot \cot(x)} = dx$, and
$\csc^{-1} u = x$

This gives

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    \int x \cdot \frac{\cot(x) \cdot \csc(x) }{\cot(x) \cdot \csc(x)} \cdot (-1) \mathop{du}
    &= 
    \int \csc^{-1} (u) (-1) \mathop{du}
    \\
    &= 
    - \int \csc^{-1} (u)  \mathop{du}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Then using integration by parts

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    - \int \csc^{-1} (u)  \mathop{du}
    &=
    - \left(
      u \cdot \csc^{-1}(u) - \int u \cdot \frac{1}{u \sqrt{u^2 - 1}}
    \right)
    \\
    &=
    - u \cdot \csc^{-1}(u) + \int u \cdot \frac{1}{u \sqrt{u^2 - 1}}
    \\
    &=
    - u \cdot \csc^{-1}(u) + \int  \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2 - 1}}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

For the integral $\int  \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2 - 1}}$  let $k = u^2$, then
$\frac{dk}{2u} = du$

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{ u^2 - 1}} &=
    \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{k - 1}}  \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{k}} \mathop{dk}
    \\
    &=
    \frac{1}{2}
    \int \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ k}  \sqrt{k - 1}} \mathop{dk}
    \\
    &=
    \frac{1}{2} \sec^{-1} \left( \sqrt{ k}  \right)
    \\
    &=
    \frac{1}{2} \sec^{-1} \left( u \right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

.
.
.

I'm not sure what's going wrong - the rest of the working is messy, and I can't seem to find the error by checking or using CAS.

Comment: Did you try to integrate by parts? Moving the derivative from the trigonometric product to the $x$ looks promising.

Comment: @mickep yes - this is integration by parts as far as I'm aware?

Comment: i'm not sure what you're referring to about moving the derivative though

Comment: hint: Recall $\frac{d}{dx}(-\csc(x))=\cot(x) \csc(x)$

Comment: HINT: your Integrand is equivalent to $$\frac{2x\cos(x)}{2(\cos(x)^2-1)}$$

Comment: As @randomgirl writes it, so you have $x$ times the derivative of $-\csc x$. By using integration by parts you can move the derivative from the $-\csc x$ to the $x$, and you will end up with finding a primitive of $\csc x$.

Comment: i'm not sure whether these suggestions are starting afresh or from a particular point in the above

Comment: A fresh new look.  $\int x \cdot (\cot(x) \csc(x)) dx$ is your integral.  We are noticing the "basic" antiderivative of $\cot(x) \csc(x)$ is $-\csc(x)$ and the derivative of $x$ is 1. Integration by parts this way should lead to an easier path.

Comment: @randomgirl thanks - i can't seem to get this though, and CAS is showing me solutions involving tan(x/2), which don't seem to differentiate to the original problem. So I think there's something that I've not seen before going on here

Comment: you can alos use the tan half angle substitution

Comment: I don't know how to use that - it's not been covered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Integrate by parts with $u=x$ and $v=-\csc(x)$.  This yields

$$\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} x\cot(x)\csc(x)\,dx= \left.\left (-x\csc(x)\right)\right|_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}+\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\csc(x)\,dx$$

Can you finish?

Comment: i think i get a hyperbolic tan antiderivative?

Comment: Did you mean inverse hyperbolic?

Comment: yeah, though it's still super messy! `>.<` I have $$-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\pi + \ln( - 3 - 2 \sqrt{2}   ) $$ and i'm not sure where the additional signs and values have come from but i give up :'(

Comment: Recall that $$\int \csc(x)\,dx=-\log(\cot(x)+\csc(x))+C$$Now you can finish.